# How to change the logging level in liquibase version 3.6.3

Tags: liquibase

I hate to post this question because it has been asked for many versions of liquibase, but I cannot change the logging level for version 3.6.3. I've tried the suggestions for the other versions without any success...

POM:

```
<liquibase.logging>INFO</liquibase.logging>
```

and

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <logging>${liquibase.logging}</logging>
        ...
    </configuration>
```

When I run mvn, I still get DEBUG level messages from Liquibase

```
07:09:29.541 [main] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Searching for all classes in package: liquibase/change using classloader: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm
07:09:29.541 [main] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Getting resource URL for package: liquibase/change with classloader: ClassRealm[plugin>org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.6.3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7852e922]
07:09:29.542 [main] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - URL from classloader: jar:file:/home/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.6.3/liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar!/liquibase/change/
07:09:29.543 [main] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.DefaultPackageScanClassResolver - Decoded urlPath: file:/home/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.6.3/liquibase-core-3.6.3.jar!/liquibase/change/ with protocol: jar0
etc.
```

I've also tried the -Dliquibase.logging=info on the mvn command line and I get the same results.

Answer (score -1):

There were several bugs related to logging in Liquibase 3.6.x. These have been fixed in version 3.8.1 and greater.